# CKeditor Preview Plugin.js, editing for Chrome and IE. As it refuses CSS style

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, preview

I am integrating WYSIWYG editor for a fairly simple CMS. I have chosen CKeditor and use the 'preview' button. This thing is that it is inconsistent in the three main browsers. (IE, Chrome and Firefox).

If you have ever used CKeditor you will know within the files that come with it there are two locations to find 'preview.html'. These being:

```
http://sitename/ckeditor/plugins/preview
```

and

```
http://sitename/ckeditor/_source/plugins/preview
```

The latter also contains a plugin.js file that relates to the preview plugin, and where I feel the answer to my question lies. This code can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/keKLP/

Just so that you can see it. Now the problem is that the preview by default is just plain text. So I edited the preview.html pages and wrapped the bit of code that pulls the content from the editor in HTML including style sheet references and images paths. In firefox this works fine, but only in Firefox. In chrome and IE it pulls through no style, no images, nothing. When I looked into it I noticed that the Firefox preview opens up a new window that points to an actual address. The address being:

```
http://mysite.co.uk/ckeditor/plugins/preview/preview.html
```

where as IE and Chrome open a new window/tab pointing to:

```
about:blank
```

Having looked through that JavaScript file (plugin.js) listed above, I can see it does something different for Firefox than other browsers. I have changed almost everything that say 'path' or 'URL' in the file trying to get it to point to the same place as Firefox in other browsers instead of about:blank.

However I am no JavaScript expert and I feel my understanding of the exact problem is lacking. It's driving me crazy, can anyone point me to a bit of JavaScript in that file I should be looking at, or shed some light on the problem? ANY help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possible way for tracing through the preview plugins .js file and trying to edit the way it calls the preview pop-up. However this is long winded and problematic, as it always seems to work better in firefox than any other browser.

My solution to this was to remove ckeditor and implment TinyMCE. The preview page is alot easier to edit and caused no problems at all.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved that issue adding my own custom files (css, js, meta, etc.) into ckeditor.js. I created a string variable containing html code (with link, meta, scripts) like this:

```
var my_includefiles='<link href="http://assets.mydomain.com/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" /><link href="http://assets.mydomain.com/css/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8"/><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';
```

And I just added my var to this portion of code (part of _cke_htmlToLoad):

```
a=a.config.docType+'<html dir="'+a.config.contentsLangDirection+'"><head>'+e+CKEDITOR.tools.buildStyleHtml(a.config.contentsCss)+my_includefiles+"<title>"+a.lang.preview.preview+"</title></head>"+(b+">")+a.getData()+"</body></html>"
```

After that, preview with my own custom styles and behaviors worked fine in IE9, FF19, Opera12 but not in Chrome (25), so to make it work in Chrome I removed this portion of code of ckeditor.js

```
CKEDITOR.env.webkit&&setTimeout(function(){f.body.innerHTML=f.body.innerHTML+""},0)
```

That resolved the problem. I hope it help.